# Tribonacci Code $K(C)=1$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, information-theory, coding-theory, compression

*Motivation:* The following is a problem I encountered some time ago and it bothers me since I did not solve it as expected. My original way to solve it was using calculus, however, I was expected to solve it with information theory knowledge. I also provide what I think was the intention of the author. However, I am not sure how to execute this "plan".

*Question:* Let $C$ be some code with $T_i$ codewords of length $i$, where $T_i$ satisfies the following recurrence relation:

1. $T_5=2,T_4=T_3=1$.
2. $T_{n+1}=T_n+T_{n-1}+T_{n-2}$

We need to show that
$$ K(C):=\sum_{c\in C} 2^{-|c|}=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}T_i\cdot 2^i=1$$
The first equality was an instruction, and the second was the claim to be shown. The solution should use methods from information theory and data compression.

I guess we needed to show that the code is complete, i.e., every node in the tree has $0$ or $2$ children, and then by Kraft's inequality $K(C)=1$.

*Discrete Math Version.* Consider a tree, where the number of leaves at depth $i-1$ is $T_i$. We need to show that every node in the tree has $0$ or $2$ children.

Comment: I don't think your translation into graph theory is correct. If $T_i=1$, then there is a vertex at depth $i-1$ of degree $1$, and you're assuming $1=T_3 = T_4$. This contradicts the statement you wanted to show.

Comment: @MathieuRundström. A more accurate way is to say that $T_i$ is the number of leaves at depth $i-1$ since a leaf is a codeword. The example you provided is not a counter-example.